Statistical analysis of radiolocational information
Let's consider the following system:

A radar station designed to track a moving target. Sensor equipment that allows measuring its position, speed and other parameters if necessary.

What is interesting: is statistical processing of the measured radar information carried out, what methods are used for this, and what useful information can be extracted using statistical processing of radilocational information (for example, in terms of errors or maneuvers, etc.)?
Details: I am currently working with radar data. These are time series that include measured values ​​of position, velocity and acceleration of an object tracked by radar. The data is noisy. The noise is unknown, but presumably Gaussian. Next, I will work with filtering algorithms. But first, I would like to calculate some statistical properties of the noise, something related to errors, some distributions, etc. I have not encountered such a task before, so I do not know what is included in the framework of statistical processing of radar data.
